# drupal 7 content type field that is the result of a view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, content-type

Drupal 7: I am looking for a content type field that is generated from the result of a view.

Example: I have a courses content type and I have a course_outline content type. In the course_outline content type I would like to list all the existing courses available in the database as one of its fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to install [Entity API module](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity reference module](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

You can check out [Entity Reference Module guide for beginners](http://drupal.org/node/1327954) to get started.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Glad it helped. Kindly consider mark the answer as the accepted one, so others who have the same issue can benefit form it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, this is my first posting so I am a newbie

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a field that you can add (through the GUI) to your content type to refer to a View, check out [**viewfield  module**](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield)

> Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
>   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.

However, there are other ways of achieving what you want including using Entity References (as described in the other answer to this question) or you could also write your own module to insert the appropriate view when rendering the node.